# IO Thread checkout/release strategy RXJAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, observable, rx-java

I am using `RX-Java 1.3.8` and for demonstrating the problem, i have modified the IO scheduler `CacheThreadScheduler` to log statement like `getting thread with $id` when a thread worker is taken from the queue and `releasing thread with $id` when thread worker is returned to the queue.

Now consider the scenario where we want to make an async-io HTTP call and then using the result of it, make another async-io HTTP call.
Below code demonstrate this
`In the example have used executor service to simulate the async-io HTTP call`

```
1. Observable.just("1")
2.          .doOnNext(s -> print("just started"))
3.          .flatMap(one -> {
4.              return Observable.create(sub -> {
5.                  // simulating an async io http request which take 10 sec
6.                  Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(() -> {
7.                      sleep(10_000);                      
8.                      print("GOT RESPONSE-1");
9.                      sub.onNext("");sub.onCompleted();
10.                 });
11.             });
12.         })
13.         .doOnNext((s) -> print("before moving to io thread"))
14.         .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
15.         .doOnNext((s) -> print("after moving to io thread"))
16.         .flatMap(two -> {
17.             return Observable.create(sub -> {
18.                 Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(() -> {
19.                         // simulating an async io http request which take 10 sec
20.                     sleep(10_000);
21.                     print("GOT RESPONSE-2");
22.                     sub.onNext("");sub.onCompleted();
23.                 });
24.             });
25.         })
26.         .doOnNext((s) -> print("close to end of chain"))            
27.         .subscribe();
```

OUTPUT GOT:

```
1. getting thread worker with id ThreadWorker@1d251891
2. main:just started
3. pool-1-thread-1:GOT RESPONSE-1
4. pool-1-thread-1:before moving to io thread
5. RxCachedThreadScheduler-1:after moving to io thread
6. pool-2-thread-1:GOT RESPONSE-2
7. pool-2-thread-1:close to end of chain
8. releasing thread worker with id ThreadWorker@1d251891 in 2011
```

Now if we analys the output the first thing it did is checkout a thread worker from CacheThreadScheduler, which is a not desirable as we expect the threadwork should be checkedout after `GOT RESPONSE-1` gets printed.

**Question1**: Can this be forced that threadworker gets checkout only after `GOT RESPONSE-1` is printed?

Second thing to look at is `line 8`, the threadworker is release after the pipe line gets completed, it is expected that threadworker should get release as soon as `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit` gets call.

**Question2**: Can this be forced that threadworker gets release after `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit` is called.